# PHP MySQL delete row

Tags: php, mysql, delete-row, corresponding-records

I have searched everywhere and cannot find the answer, I believe I have the correct code but there could be a typo.

What is going wrong here?

I have the link that posts the product id correctly to the url as shown:

`userAccount.php`:

```
while($columnDelete = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        echo "<section class='product'>
                <a href='extras/deleteProcess.php?productId=".$columnDelete['productId']."' class='deleteProduct' style='color:#990000;font-family:arial;font-weight:bold;font-size:12pt;background:transparent;'>Delete?</a>
                <section class='productImg'>
                    <a target='_self' href='fullProductInfo.php?productId=".$columnDelete['productId']."'>
                        <img src='http://www.littlepenguindesigns.co.uk/pages/CMX/images/products/".$columnDelete['productImg']."' alt='".$columnDelete['productName']."' border='0' width='230' height='200' border='0' />
                    </a>
                </section>
                <section class='productName'><a target='_self' href='fullProductInfo.php?productId=".$columnDelete['productId']."'>".$columnDelete['productName']."</a></section>
                <section class='productPrice'>&pound;".$columnDelete['price']."</section></section>";
    }
```

The `$columnDelete['productId'];` is posting the correct ID to the url and the `deleteProcess.php` page, I can see the `productId` in the URL and I have also echoed it out onto the page to check, it does show:

`deleteProcess.php`:

```
$productId = $_GET['productId'];
$con = mysqli_connect("BLAH","BLAH","BLAH","BLAH") or die('Server connection not possible.');
$sql = ("DELETE FROM `product` WHERE `product`.`productId`= $productId");
mysqli_query($con, $sql);

echo "Deleted product ID: $productId successfully.<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /> <a href='../userAccount.php#deletion'>Go back to user account and delete another.</a>";
```

I cannot understand what is going on, the product gets called into `deleteProcess.php` and onto the page but doesn't delete, it shows no errors either. As I'm newish to php and mysql I thought I'd best research, as I came up with no answer I thought to ask, so can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong or point me in the right direction.

Comment: check if mysql connected or not

Comment: echo the query and then run directly into phpmyadmin and then see waht is the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = ("DELETE FROM `product` WHERE `product`.`productId`= $productId");
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

to

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM `product` WHERE `product`.`productId`= $productId";
mysqli_query($con,$sql) OR DIE(mysqli_error($con)); //useful for debugging
```

**warning!** this code is vulnerable to SQL injection.
fix sql injection by sanitizing all user input.

```
$productId = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['productId']); // use mysql_real_escape_string on $_GET
$con = mysqli_connect("BLAH","BLAH","BLAH","BLAH") or die('Server connection not possible.');
$sql = "DELETE FROM `product` WHERE `product`.`productId`= '$productId'"; //add single quotes around variable $productid to seperate string from query
mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check query execution return success or not

```
$productId = $_GET['productId'];
$con = mysqli_connect("BLAH","BLAH","BLAH","BLAH") or die('Server connection not possible.');
$sql = ("DELETE FROM `product` WHERE `product`.`productId`= $productId");

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if(!$result)
   die("Query failed".mysql_error());

echo "Deleted product ID: $productId successfully.<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /> <a href='../userAccount.php#deletion'>Go back to user account and delete another.</a>";
```